# Dismiss Ionic 4 popover from its component

Tags: popover, ionic4

I have a standard Ionic 4 page (Home) that creates a popover that uses a component (BusinessDetails) with a button that redirects to a new page (RequestTurn). However, when I click on that button, the popover is not dismissed and is renders on top of my RequestTurn page. I guess I need to manually dismiss it from the component (BusinessDetails), but I don't know how to access the instance of the popover from there, because it was created in the Home page. Is there a way to do this?

home.page.ts

```
presentModal(business:Business, event: Event) {
this.popoverController.create(({
    component: BusinessDetailsComponent,
    cssClass: "business-popover",
    showBackdrop: true,
    componentProps: {
        business: business
    }
}) as any).then(popover => popover.present()); }
```

business-detail.component.ts

```
goToRequestTurn(id: string) {
   //Need to dismiss popver here (?)
   this.router.navigateByUrl(`/request-turn/${id}`); }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I ended up passing the popoverController instance from Home to BusinessDetails, and the using that instance to dismiss it. However, I'm not sure that's the best approach, or if there's a more straightforward method.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

add  `private popoverController: PopoverController` to the component constructor

then write a function like this and call it when you want to dismiss the modal

```
 async DismissClick() {
await this.popoverController.dismiss();
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean "to the component constructor"? Because that's where I need to dismiss it from, but it looks to me like doing that will inject a new instance of the controller, so would not be dismissing the original one. I'll give it a try, anyway. Thanks.

Comment: yes the component constructor,sorry my mistake.let me know if you succeeded. good luck

Comment: It did work, thanks for the help. So, that means that the PopoverController you inject is actually a sinlgeton, correct? Otherwise, why would it close the instance injected to the constructor of the Home page?

Comment: Thank you, it helped me . Very strange, but the first time it did not work. When I tried this method after a while, it started working O_o

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem as follows:
In parent component I have passed callback as prop to child component:

```js
const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
  component: PopoverComponent,
  event: ev,
  componentProps: {
    onClick: () => {
      popover.dismiss();
    },
  },
});
await popover.present();
```

And in PopoverComponent I have added `@Input() onClick;` which called when the user clicks:

```js
...
@Input()
public onClick = () => {}
...
afterClick() {
  this.onClick();
}
```

Comment: Wrong. you are taking input as 'onClick' and on 'afterClick' writing 'this.click()'

Comment: Kudos, very clever indeed!